# Query for multiple rows in SQLitefor Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This is just an simplified version of a DB I am using:

[image: Sample DB]

Lets say if I wanted to query to get IDs 101, 102, 114, 212, and 256.

```
cursorLoader = new MyCursorLoader(getActivity()) {

                @Override
                public Cursor loadInBackground() {

                    Cursor c = null;

                    String selection = COL_PERSON_ID + " = ?";
                    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"101","102","114","212","256"};

                     c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);

                    return c;
                }
            };
```

After running this I get a crash,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 5 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.
```

I found related posts but nothing that could answer what I needed.

Comment: You probably want something like: `String selection = COL_PERSON_ID + " IN(?,?,?,?,?)";`.

Comment: That did it! Ill comment back here if there is anything else related to this. 
Thanks!